# How configure the DHCP settings of WIFI Tethering (Hotspot) on Android?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, ip-address

When connecting my PC to Android Wi-Fi hotspot, it assigned a `192.168.42.x` address to my PC. I really need to change this as it conflicts with one of our work subnets - is this possible?

Comment: My mobile is rooted. I don't mind changing system files if required.

Comment: Just as response to nuances in some of the above great answers, in my practice the 192.168.43.0/24 range is by Android/vendor default assigned for WiFi tethering and 192.168.42.0/24 is for USB tethering.

Comment: [How to change the default DHCP IP address range?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214072/218526)

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the IP address range for the builtin tethering support, even in CyanogenMod. The Wi-Fi hotspot IP is hardcoded in [android.net.wifi.WifiStateMachine.startTethering()](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java?source=c#L1301); the USB tethering IP is hardcoded in [com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/services/java/com/android/server/connectivity/Tethering.java?source=cc#L110).

However, if your phone is rooted, you can try using third-party apps for tethering which have the option to change the IP address range. E.g., when the builtin USB tethering was broken in CyanogenMod alphas for Samsung Galaxy W, I used [Wired Tether for Root Users](http://code.google.com/p/android-wired-tether/), which has such option. For Wi-Fi tethering you can try the [Wireless Tether for Root Users](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) app from the same authors, which also has the option to change the IP address range.

---

Because Google Code was shut down, the above links no longer work. Some people exported the source code from those repositories to GitHub:

- https://github.com/luftreich/android-wired-tether
- https://github.com/mmorciegov/android-wifi-tether

However, there was no further development activity, and the apps probably no longer work on recent Android versions.

Just in case someone wants to try those obsolete apps, I have been able to find some APK files in the [Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/schema):

- [wired_tether_1_4.apk](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/android-wired-tether/wired_tether_1_4.apk)
- [wifi_tether_v3_4-experimental1.apk](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/android-wifi-tether/wifi_tether_v3_4-experimental1.apk)

Comment: +1 for the info. My device is rooted, but Wireless Tether for Root Users app is not working on my mobile. There should be some way to change the IP range on the rooted phone, C'Mon Man!, Android is an open OS after all.

Comment: @VVK There is a way. Just recompile the source.

Comment: On Android 11 it seems my gateway IP of my hotspot is changing every time I disable and enable the hotspot, again. So this answer is outdated for the latest Android. The question is now, is there a solution, eventually?

Answer (score 25):

The Android built-in WiFi tethering is designed to use `192.168.43.1/24` as the server, with `netd` handling the tethering, using `dnsmasq`. The first DNS range is `192.168.42.1-254` and 2nd DNS range is `192.168.43.1-254`.

Netd is not easy to change. It requires a socket to communicate with it, and that socket is taken when Android starts tethering. But going through the source files for `Tethering.java` (I used Froyo) we see:

```
// usb client will be provided 192.168.42.129
private static final String USB_NEAR_IFACE_ADDR      = "192.168.42.129";
private static final String USB_NETMASK              = "255.255.255.0";

// FYI - the default wifi is 192.168.43.1 and 255.255.255.0

private String[] mDhcpRange;
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_START = "192.168.42.2";
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_STOP  = "192.168.42.254";
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_START = "192.168.43.2";
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_STOP  = "192.168.43.254";
```

And later on, we see those ranges used, **AS BACKUPS**.

```
mDhcpRange = context.getResources().getStringArray(
        com.android.internal.R.array.config_tether_dhcp_range);
if ((mDhcpRange.length == 0) || (mDhcpRange.length % 2 ==1)) {
    mDhcpRange = new String[4];
    mDhcpRange[0] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_START;
    mDhcpRange[1] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_STOP;
    mDhcpRange[2] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_START;
    mDhcpRange[3] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_STOP;
}
```

The main source for the DHCP ranges is not the hardcoded 42 and 43, but read from `array.config_tether_dhcp_range`, an internal string array. But it is currently empty.

You could edit the Android framework. On my phone, it is `/system/framework/framework-res.apk`. There are a **ton** of tutorials online for editing `framework-res.apk`, from simple strings to full theming. Find one for your phone and Android version.

The main thing you want to change is the `/res/values/arrays.xml`

Look for `<array name="config_tether_dhcp_range" />`. Change to:

```
<string-array name="config_tether_dhcp_range">
     <item>192.168.x.y</item>
     <item>192.168.x.z</item>
</string-array>
```

compile/zip/sign as needed (follow a tutorial), then reinstall.

If you want more than one range, just copy the two items over and over. You always need to provide a start and a stop for each range. Try to keep it in the same /24, ie `192.168.50.`5 and `192.168.50.99` or whatever. You can confirm it is working with `busybox ps | grep dnsmasq`, or if you don't have busybox `ps dnsmasq` then use the pid in `cat /proc/pid/cmdline`. You should get (or similar):

> /system/bin/dnsmasq --no-daemon --no-poll -no-resolv --dhcp-range=192.168.50.5,192.168.50.99,1h

FWIW, my WiFi tethering uses the default `dnsmasq` ranges, yet my computer was assigned `192.168.43.147/24` and gateway `192.168.43.1/24`. Not sure why yours defaulted to a `42.x` address.

Comment: 42 is for USBNET 43 is for wifi

Comment: Because if you tether by usb you get 42. If you tether by wifi you get 43.

Comment: i am on android 11 and it assigns IP even from 192.168.17.*. Looks like ranges have changed

Comment: @just yeah its completely revamped. https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/tethering no longer part of framework its been moved to its own replaceable module. And it still depends on your manufacturer customization.

Answer (score 5):

It appears some manufacturers and versions of Android now DO allow for the changing of the IP subnet range for the DHCP server through the UI when using the WiFi hotspot feature.  Here's where to find it on an HTC One M8 running Android 6.0.  YMMV.

From the Mobile Hotspot screen, click the 3 dots icon (more), go to Advanced, then LAN settings.
Under "Local IP" change the IP address to your desired IP.  Under "Local DHCP" change the starting IP to match the subnet of your IP address.

Comment: Do you know if new HTC phones also have this option?

Answer (score 2):

Default DHCP IP address range is hard-coded, so you can't change it without rebuilding ROM with modified source code. Or use a little hack. Replace `/system/bin/dnsmasq` (the DHCP/DNS server up to Android 9) with a custom shell script which replaces old subnet with new one before executing actual `dnsmasq` binary.

For detailed steps see [How to change the default DHCP IP address range?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214072/218526)

Comment: What does Android 10 use now?

Comment: @sudo Java implementation of DHCP/DNS server. But at least some ROMs still use `dnsmasq`.

Comment: @Irfan what is the procedure in the implementation?

Comment: @JustKhaithang see my comments [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233453/how-can-i-permanently-assign-a-static-ip-address-to-wi-fi-clients-lineage-os-1#comment309009_233453) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232041/hosting-a-hotspot-without-signaling-metered-connection#comment305627_232041).

Comment: Good old wrappers.

Comment: DHCP ranges are not configurable as of now in newer Androids, see the code for details, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r45/packages/Tethering/src/com/android/networkstack/tethering/PrivateAddressCoordinator.java?autodive=0%2F#148

Answer (score 1):

Now they're dynamic.  I have a device that when connected to the phone hotspot gets the address 192.168.XXX.85 where XXX changes all the time, possibly daily or with every reboot.