# Does Android have a "router setup page" when acting as a wireless or wired hotspot?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot

I can edit all the crucial aspects of my hotspot/router within the setup options for the hotspot/router configuration.

I am confused as to how the DHCP works when using up the Android phone as a wireless hotspot/router and [wanted to figure that out](https://superuser.com/questions/614171/how-can-i-determine-the-ip-addresses-allocated-by-dhcp-on-a-router-that-im-conn).

One of my attempts to get this information for myself was to try and navigate to `192.168.6.1` via a web browser - this is, of course, the phone's IP address.  I was hoping to see some sort of router setup page as you would normally see when configuring a normal ethernet wired/wireless router via a web browser, but unfortunately, there was no such page.

I did some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288243/get-gateway-ip-address-in-android) and found out that you can get some basic information about the phone's IP configuration by downloading a terminal emulator and running a few basic *nix flavored commands.

I was looking for something more - a GUI would be excellent, but I'll take any suggestions on how to access the phone's routing configuration specs.

Is there any sort of "router setup page" that I can access when I enable my wireless hotspot on my Android phone?

Comment: See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46502/11251) — if you are using the builtin tethering support, there is no configuration, IP addresses used for Wi-Fi hotspot and USB tethering are hardcoded.

Comment: Up to Pie `dnsmasq` is Android's DHCP/DNS server. You can configure it somewhat through [`dnsmasq.conf`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dnsmasq/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/dnsmasq.conf.example) e.g. to [permanently assign a static IP address to tethered clients](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213774/218526), or through some hacks e.g. to [permanently change hotspot tethering IP address](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213626/218526) or to [change the default hotspot DHCP IP address range](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214072/218526).

Answer (score 3):

The Android builtin wifi tethering is designed to use 192.168.43.1/24 as the server, with netd handling the tethering, using dnsmasq. First DNS range is 192.168.42.1-254 and and 2nd DNS range is 192.168.43.1-254.

Netd is not easy to change. It requires a socket to communicate with it, and that socket is taken when android starts tethering. But going through the source files for Tethering.java (I used Froyo) we see:

```
// usb client will be provided 192.168.42.129
private static final String USB_NEAR_IFACE_ADDR      = "192.168.42.129";
private static final String USB_NETMASK              = "255.255.255.0";

// FYI - the default wifi is 192.168.43.1 and 255.255.255.0

private String[] mDhcpRange;
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_START = "192.168.42.2";
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_STOP  = "192.168.42.254";
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_START = "192.168.43.2";
private static final String DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_STOP  = "192.168.43.254";
```

And Later on we see those ranges used, **AS BACKUPS**.

```
    mDhcpRange = context.getResources().getStringArray(
            com.android.internal.R.array.config_tether_dhcp_range);
    if ((mDhcpRange.length == 0) || (mDhcpRange.length % 2 ==1)) {
        mDhcpRange = new String[4];
        mDhcpRange[0] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_START;
        mDhcpRange[1] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE1_STOP;
        mDhcpRange[2] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_START;
        mDhcpRange[3] = DHCP_DEFAULT_RANGE2_STOP;
    }
```

The main source for the dhcp ranges is not the hardcoded 42 and 43, but read from array.config_tether_dhcp_range, an internal string array. But it is currently empty.

You could edit the android framework. On my phone, it is /system/framework/framework-res.apk. There are a **ton** of tutorials online for editing framework-res.apk, from simple strings to full theming. Find one for your phone and android version.

Main thing you want to change is the /res/values/arrays.xml

Look for `<array name="config_tether_dhcp_range" />`

Change to:

```
<string-array name="config_tether_dhcp_range">
     <item>192.168.x.y</item>
     <item>192.168.x.z</item>
</string-array>
```

compile/zip/sign as needed (follow a tutorial), then reinstall.

If you want more than one range, just copy the two items over and over. You always need to provide a start and a stop for each range. Try to keep it in the same /24, ie 192.168.50.5 and 192.168.50.99 or whatever. You can confirm it is working with `busybox ps | grep dnsmasq` or if you don't have busybox `ps dnsmasq` then use the pid in `cat /proc/pid/cmdline`. You should get (or similar):

> /system/bin/dnsmasq --no-daemon --no-poll -no-resolv --dhcp-range=192.168.50.5,192.168.50.99,1h

FWIW, my WIFI tethering uses the default dnsmasq ranges, yet my computer was assigned 192.168.43.147/24 and gateway 192.168.43.1/24. Not sure why yours defaulted to a 42.x address.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, using "Ethernet Tethering" on my Samsung S20, My attached device gets a 192.168.13.200/24 address and a 192.168.13.25 gateway.

Interestingly, my "Net Analyzer" app shows my phone's external IP as 172.58.200.200 and an internal IP of 33.15.32.108/28.

How many routers are there in my phone...?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/250587)