# How can I permanently change my hotspot tethering IP address?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, ip-address, gateway

IP address is `192.168.43.1` by default and there is no option to change it permanently. Is it possible to change it without root access?

My phone is Huawei Android 5.1.

Comment: [How configure the DHCP settings of WIFI Tethering (Hotspot) on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Note:*** Adding / removing IP address requires root access.

---

**METHOD 1:**

Before Android Pie, tethering IP (`192.168.43.1`) was hard-coded <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r65/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#69), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r65/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#193))</sup>. But now it's randomized on each session<sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#210))</sup>. You can use Android's builtin `ip` command to set an additional fixed IP address (within same subnet obviously):

```
~# ip address add 192.168.43.100/24 dev wlan0
```

<sup>* Replace `add` with `del` to delete.</sup>

Make sure that the name of your Wi-Fi interface (`wlan0` usually) is correct. Check with `ip link` or `ls /sys/class/net` or `iw dev`.

---

**METHOD 2:**

The problem with above approach is that the **added IP is not permanent**. Once you switch OFF the hotspot, IP will get cleared. So you can use an `init` trigger to set IP address whenever hotspot is turned ON. Add these lines to `(/vendor)/etc/init/hostapd.android.rc` file (or any `.rc` file under `/etc/init/`):

```
on property:init.svc.hostapd=running
    exec - -- /system/bin/sleep 2
    exec u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/ip address add 192.168.43.100/24 dev wlan0
```

- `hostapd` is the system service which manages access points.
- Service uses Magisk's SELinux context assuming that the device is rooted with Magisk.

---

**METHOD 3:**

`dnsmasq` starts listening on all IP addresses which are set on WiFi interface before `dnsmasq` is started. But with both above methods there is no way to make sure that IP is added after `netd` sets up the interface and before `dnsmasq` starts. So the added **IP address may conflict** with IP leased to another host (saved in `/data/misc/dhcp/dnsmasq.leases`) by DHCP server (`dnsmasq` up to Pie) from DHCP range (`192.168.43.2` to `192.168.43.254` by default) <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetheringConfiguration.java#76))</sup>.

To address this problem:

- Reserve the manually added IP address by editing `dnsmasq.conf`. See [How can I permanently assign a static IP address to Wi-Fi or USB tether clients?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213774/218526)
- Or modify DHCP IP range, but it's hard coded. You can replace `dnsmasq` with a shell script to achieve this. See [How to change the default hotspot DHCP IP address range?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214072/218526)
- Or replace `/system/bin/dnsmasq` with a shell script which adds IP address before executing original `dnsmasq` binary. Rename `dnsmasq` to `dnsmasq.bin` and create script: `/system/bin/dnsmasq`:

  ```
  #!/system/bin/sh

  # set fixed IP address on Wi-Fi interface
  ip address add 192.168.43.100/24 dev wlan0

  # execute original binary
  exec dnsmasq.bin $*
  ```

  - Set ownership, permission and SELinux context on both files. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214072/218526) for details.
  - Additionally you may add `listen-address=192.168.43.100` <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dnsmasq/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/dnsmasq.conf.example#88))</sup> to `dnsmasq.conf`.
  - Use `ss` or `netstat` to make sure that DHCP server is listening on reserved IP address (or on all IP addresses i.e. `0.0.0.0`) so that to avoid IP address collision.

**NOTE** that in order to modify `.rc`, `dnsmasq` or `dnsmasq.conf` files, `/vendor` and `/system` partitions need to be mounted R/W which requires [`dm-verity` disabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526). Otherwise you may use bind mounts (used by Magisk modules). On non-[SAR](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) devices `/init.rc` can also be edited to modify `/init.rc` file in ramdisk by unpacking `boot.img`.

Comment: I was able to set this up on a MotoG3 turbo with LineageOS 17.1 android-10.

Comment: Hi, I just want to clarify that this Q&A is about setting the Android's hotspot IP to static, but not the given IP to the devices that are connected to the hotspot right? I did a peek at deleted comments and looks like there was also confusion, so just to be sure before I wrongly close other questions as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes. This question is about the **hotspot IP address of the Android device**. There's another question about the **IP addresses assigned to the devices connected to the Android hotspot**: [How can I permanently assign a static IP address to Wi-Fi or USB tether clients?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213670/218526).