# How can I permanently change my USB tethering IP address?

Tags: tethering, usb-tethering

Question is: How can I permanently change my USB tethering IP address?
Using Android 11 with a known problem of changing IPs.
Only answer I found is [How can I permanently change my hotspot tethering IP address?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213514/how-can-i-permanently-change-my-hotspot-tethering-ip-address) by @irfan-latif .
It would be best to comment there, but I do not have 50 points...

Problem is that I could not make fixed Android IP when tethering USB. I have rooted Andorid with Magisk, which I understood is a requirement.
With Method 2, I added to /etc/init/usbd.rc (there it is said any .rc file) this, changing to rndis0:

```
on property:init.svc.hostapd=running
    exec - -- /system/bin/sleep 2
    exec u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/ip address add 192.168.43.100/24 dev rndis0
```

But I do not see it working, also 'ip address' on Android does not show that range.
Note: there is a related question at [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225643/how-to-make-ethernet-work-on-android-over-otg/225741#225741).

Anyone may also help with mentioning this question there, hopefully mr. Latif would notice.