# How can I permanently assign a static IP address to Wi-Fi or USB tether clients?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, 7.1-nougat, wifi-tethering

I use my phone as an extended display with `x11vnc`, which works as intended. 
The only issue is, that I have to change the IP address on the VNC client on my phone, very often. Because of dynamic DHCP, I suppose.
I use a Motorola g Turbo Lineage OS 7.1.2, rooted.

Is Android capable of IP reservation? It basically assigns IP address and hostname depending on the MAC address. Or something that achieves the same.

**Edit:**

Is it possible to assign new static lease through an ADB command immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android uses `dnsmasq` as its DHCP/DNS server (up to Pie). So create the configuration file `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` with option `dhcp-host=<MAC>,<IP>` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dnsmasq/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/dnsmasq.conf.example#154))</sup>.

Root is required to place this file. Since `/etc` is a symlink to `/system/etc`, `/system` partition needs to be mounted `R/W`. Make sure you don't break `dm-verity` if enabled on your device.

Set permissions:

```
~# chown 0.0 /etc/dnsmasq.conf
~# chmod 0644 /etc/dnsmasq.conf
~# chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

SELinux rules also need to be defined if status is `enforcing`. Use Magisk's `suploicy` or some other similar tool like `sepolicy-inject`:

```
allow dnsmasq system_file file { read getattr open }
allow dnsmasq system_file dir { search }
```

> Is it possible to assign new static lease through an ADB command immediately?

No, you need to modify configuration file and restart the `dnsmasq` server (switch Hotspot <kbd>OFF</kbd> and <kbd>ON</kbd>) for changes to take effect.

Comment: what about android q?

Comment: @HakunaMatata too lazy to test so far. Will update.

Comment: Because dnsmasq has been deleted.

Comment: and what Android uses instead of dnsmasq?