# How to change the default hotspot DHCP IP address range on Android?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering, dhcp

As the title says I look for a way to permanently change the default IP address range form `192.168.43.xxx` to `192.168.1.xxx`.

Reason: On my router some of my devices get a static IP trough DHCP, in the `192.168.1.xxx` range. Using the hotspot on the road I would like to have the same setup.

I have tried [to change the range](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android) following this steps, but it did not work out on both of my devices. They are rooted and Lineage OS is installed. The last answer suggest an easy way to do this, but it is not possible in Lineage OS.

Also [this post from anroidpolice.com](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/11/29/google-wifi-app-updated-advanced-lan-settings-including-router-ip-subnet/) suggests that it is possible by an app, I look for a solution to do this with `adb`. I have no access to Google Play, and do not want it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How configure the DHCP settings of WIFI Tethering (Hotspot) on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tethering-hotspot-on-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***NOTE:*** Root is required.

---

Default DHCP IP address range is hard-coded <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetheringConfiguration.java#76))</sup>, you can't change it without rebuilding ROM with modified source code. Or use a little hack.

When you switch on tethering, what happens (at least):

- `hostapd` -  the daemon which manages access points - is started.
- Network interfaces are set up, IP address is added to Wi-Fi interface (hard-coded before Android Pie <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r65/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#69), [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r65/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#193))</sup>, randomized afterwards <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#210))</sup>), and routing table is added <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetherInterfaceStateMachine.java#199))</sup> for local network.
- `dnsmasq` - the DHCP/DNS server (up to Pie) - is started with hard-coded commandline arguments <sup>([6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/server/TetherController.cpp#217))</sup> (which can be set through `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` <sup>([7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dnsmasq/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/dnsmasq.conf.example))</sup> otherwise).

So we can replace `/system/bin/dnsmasq` with a custom shell script, taking control of the process in between. Rename the original binary to something else:

```
~# mv /system/bin/dnsmasq /system/bin/dnsmasq.bin
```

Create script `/system/bin/dnsmasq`:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

OLD_SUBNET='192.168.43'
NEW_SUBNET='192.168.1'
WIFI_INTERFACE='wlan0'
LOCAL_TABLE=$(awk '$2=="local_network" {print $1}' /data/misc/net/rt_tables)

export PATH=/system/bin

# delete old route, add new
ip route del ${OLD_SUBNET}.0/24 dev ${WIFI_INTERFACE} table $LOCAL_TABLE
ip route add ${NEW_SUBNET}.0/24 dev ${WIFI_INTERFACE} table $LOCAL_TABLE

# set new IP address on Wi-Fi interface
ip address add ${NEW_SUBNET}.1/24 dev $WIFI_INTERFACE

# inject new subnet in hard-coded arguments received from netd
set -- $(printf '%s' "$*" | sed 's/'"${OLD_SUBNET}"'/'"${NEW_SUBNET}"'/g')
unset OLD_SUBNET NEW_SUBNET WIFI_INTERFACE LOCAL_TABLE

# execute original binary with new arguments
exec dnsmasq.bin $*
```

Confirm the name of your Wi-Fi interface (`wlan0` usually). Check with `ip link` or `ls /sys/class/net/` or `iw`:

```
WIFI_INTERFACE=$(iw dev | grep -E 'ssid |Interface ' | grep -B1 ssid | awk '$1=="Interface" {print $2}')
```

Also confirm your `local_network` <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/server/RouteController.cpp#72), [9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/server/RouteController.h#37))</sup> routing table (`97`) is being used for hotspot. Android's routing is a mess, getting more complex with every new release. So I'm not sure if this has been persistent or not. Also before making any changes, check your routing policies and tables to figure out what you should put in your script:

```
~# RULES="$(ip rule | grep -vE 'unreachable|local')"
~# echo "$RULES"
~# for t in $(echo "$RULES" | awk '{print $NF}' | uniq); do ip r s table $t; done
```

SELinux rules also need to be defined if (all or some) not already defined and if status is `enforcing`. Use Magisk's `suploicy` or some other similar tool like `sepolicy-inject`:

```
# execute binaries from /system/bin
allow netd system_file dir { read open getattr search }
allow netd system_file file { read gettattr open execute execute_no_trans }

# execute /system/bin/sh
allow netd shell_exec file { read getattr open execute execute_no_trans }

# execute /system/bin/toolbox and its applets
allow netd toolbox_exec file { read gettattr open execute execute_no_trans }

# configure RPDB rules / routing tables
allow netd netd capability { sys_admin }
```

<sup>* Rules are not persistent across reboots, use some `init.d` script or replace `/sepolicy` in `ramdisk`</sup>

Set permissions on files:

```
~# chown 0.0 /system/bin/dnsmasq*; chmod 0755 /system/bin/dnsmasq*
~# chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/bin/dnsmasq
~# chcon u:object_r:dnsmasq_exec:s0 /system/bin/dnsmasq.bin
```

Enjoy!

Another options is to modify the value of `config_tether_dhcp_range` <sup>([10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/tethering/TetheringConfiguration.java#280))</sup> in Android framework as explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60408/218526), but I haven't tested this.

Or you can setup complete tethering from commandline, running your own processes. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202336/218526) includes the instructions, though the question is different.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How can I permanently assign a static IP address to Wi-Fi or USB tether clients?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213774/218526)
- [How can I permanently change my hotspot tethering IP address?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213626/218526)

Comment: @Irfan Latif this does not work anymore on LineageOS 17.1 aka android 10. Could you please help to set it up there.

Comment: @kocj yes already mentioned: *"`dnsmasq` - the DHCP/DNS server (**up to Pie**) "*. I haven't tried anything on Android 10+ so far. They use Java implementation of DHCP server which isn't as easy to alter as a commandline tool is. Possibly the only way would be to patch some system file, or recompile the whole ROM after patching source code.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you for your quick repaly. LineageOS 17.1 still has the DNSmasq executable. When when i switch on the tethering i am unable to find the dnsmasq.leases file. So there have been some changes. I will open a new question for android 10

Comment: @kocj `dnsmasq` is being used as DNS server but DHCP server is moved to Java. Some related details here in comments: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232041/hosting-a-hotspot-without-signaling-metered-connection#comment305627_232041

Comment: @IrfanLatif your answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201024/how-to-use-wi-fi-and-hotspot-at-the-same-time-on-android/202335#202335 might be the way to go. The thing is that the lshw command does not work for me. Do you think that i will work on android 11 too?

Comment: @IrfanLatif i have added a new question for the topic. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233453/how-can-i-permanently-assign-a-static-ip-address-to-wi-fi-clients-lineage-os-1. I have also tried to reach out at the LinageOS folks. So far no answer.

Comment: @kocj `lshw` should work on any Linux based system, be it Android or something else. It just reads device info from `/dev`, `/sys`, `/proc` etc. which you can do manually too, except the syscalls and communication over netlink sockets. Btw if you want to create hotspot from commandline here's the starting point: [How to create a wifi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526)