# How to change the subnet mask for Wi-Fi hotspot without root access?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

If I start a Wi-Fi hotspot, devices connect with IP addresses in the range 192.168.43.xxx. How do I change that to the range 192.168.1.xxx  ?

I have read the answer to [How to change the default DHCP IP address range on Android 7.1.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214044/96277) but it requires a rooted device and I want to do this without root access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default DHCP IP address range on Android 7.1.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214044/how-to-change-the-default-dhcp-ip-address-range-on-android-7-1-2)

Comment: That would certainly do it (upvote), ***BUT*** It requires root, which I do not have on my 'phone :-(