# Portable hotspot device IP reservation

Tags: wifi-hotspot

How can you set IP reservations for devices that are connecting to the portable hotspot that is created by an android device?

Comment: Have you seen [How configure the DHCP settings of WIFI Tethering(Hotspot) in android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46499/16575)?

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I want always assign the same IP address to a certain MAC Address.

Comment: Sure. But that can be done via DHCP as well, and AFAIK that's what hotspot uses.

Comment: Correct. I'm not looking to program an app, just want to know if there is an app that already allows this, or if there is a config file somewhere. Aside, both the apps they referred didn't work on my Nexus 4 (4.4.2).

Comment: According to an [article on nascentstuff](http://nascentstuff.com/how-to-setup-wi-fi-hotspot-using-your-android-device/), there should be advanced settings in the hotspot configuration. I couldn't find them on my devices (stock 4.0.3, CM 7.2 with 2.3.6), but that might be different for you. Verizon shows a comparable [instruction for the Droid X2](http://support.verizonwireless.com/support/devices/knowledge_base.html/43163). Do any of those work for you?