# Setting static ip for Android hotspot

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I'm connecting to my Android's hotspot. I see that the IP is 192.168.43.0/24, so any ip in 192.168.43.X would be reserved for Android's DHCP server. But I need the machine that connects to Android's hotspot to have a static IP. I would have multiple Android hotspots connected to my machine using different WiFi nic cards. How would I set the static IPs in order to prevent any conflicts?

Edit:
This question asks how to configure the DHCP settings of Android 
[How configure the DHCP settings of WIFI Tethering(Hotspot) in android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android) I don't want to change DHCP settings, but I want to modify DHCP settings, but I want to set a static IP

Comment: You will need a file (an excel spreadsheet or a text file) to keep the allocated addresses, prevent allocating the same addresses twice or more to different machines. It will help differentiating and remembering the devices in case you forget. For example, you can increment the address by 1 every time you setup a new machine. If the Gateway address is 192.168.43.1, then Machine A address should be 192.168.43.2, Machine B: 192.168.43.3, Machine C: 192.168.43.4, etc.

Comment: when i was in Marshmallow (MIUI7), i set up wifi with my pc and it assigned 192.168.43.168. and since then it would assign the same IP everytime i connect to  the hotspot. Same with android 9(Oxygen OS custom ROM). then  flashed LineageOS 18.1 (based on android 11) and that set up is no more working , it is assigning new IP everytime. I am also looking for a solution to this :(